# Identifying the span of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to do a question where I'm asked to 'identify the span of the set $s={[1,-1,2],[-1,1,0]}$, I know this is the linear combination so I considered $a[1,-1,2]+b[-1,1,0]=[a-b,-a+b,2a]$ but I know I have to do more than that because the question is worth 6 marks (or just under 11 minutes in the exam), what do I do from here?

Comment: these are two vectors , what do two vectors in 3d span ? (if they are not parallel)

Comment: "Identify" is not, I believe, a mathematical term. What you did seems to be enough unless the lecturer did *something else* when using the word "identifying" . You could also remark this is a two dimensional subspace in some three dimensional space ( perhaps $\;\Bbb R^3\;$), and also that the two given vectors are a basis of this space.

Comment: $(a-b,b-a,2a) \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a correct answer. Maybe you're expected to write the answer in certain form (like $(a,-a,b)$ or $\{v : (v,(1,1,0)) = 0\}$ or $x+y=0$), but that would be your 'local' agreement and not a general rule.

Comment: The plane $x+y=0$ is definitely a safer answer!

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm glad I hadn't forgotten another vital step. As for the semantics, identify is the word used on last year's exam paper, I'm studying in the UK if that gives it any context.